# Interaction between xcolor, ulem, and no-break spaces

Tags: spacing, color, ulem

Using no-break spaces seems to break interaction between `xcolor` and `ulem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{green}{\uline{\textcolor{blue}{TeX~StackExchange}}}
\end{document}
```

What's going on? I tried wrapping the last line in `\traceon…\traceoff`, but even just that line produced about 900 lines of output, and I don't know what to make of them. The problem exists both in XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX.

[image: "StackExchange" is improperly colored]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the documentation says (emphasizing by me):

> Several text-formatting commands are specially supported within the
>   underlining: `\-`, `\` , `~`, `\\`, `\newline`, `\linebreak`, `\nolinebreak`,
>   `\penalty`, `\hskip`, `\hspace`, `\hfil`, `\hfill`, `\hss`. Displayed math is not
>   supported.
>
> **The special commands do have a problem: they end a group so
>   any local assignments are lost.**

If you want a colored text you should start the color outside `\uline`. You can get a colored rule with the commands described in the documentation too:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand\coloruline{\bgroup\markoverwith
{\textcolor{ulinecolor}{\rule[-0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}
\colorlet{ulinecolor}{green}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{\coloruline{TeX StackExchange}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; very nice. However, this new underline doesn't behave exactly the same; in particular, the width and alignment are slightly different. This is visible in particular on monospace fonts: `\makebox[0pt][l]{\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{\coloruline{v}}}}\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{\uline{v}}}`

Comment: (the difference is particularly marked with thin characters, such as `!`; I tried adjusting the length of the `\rule`, but the "right" length for `!` is too short for, say, `W`, and vice versa)