# {soul} and {xcolor} packages not working

Tags: color, soul, ulem, strikeout

I would like to strikeout a paragraph with some different text colorings in it. As I learned here: [Strikeout - when which package ? ( ulem vs soul vs ...)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74893/strikeout-when-which-package-ulem-vs-soul-vs) the `\st` command in `soul` strikesout whole paragraphs (respecting line breaks), while `\sout` in `ulem` just puts everything on one line (highly undesirable). But when I put my color commands inside `\st`, it tells me `Argument of \textcolor has an extra }.` and `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color {gray}.`!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\clight}[1]{\textcolor{white!70!black}{#1}}
\definecolor{alert}{RGB}{255, 10, 61} % 1/20/22
\newcommand{\calert}[1]{\textcolor{alert}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\clight{blah blah blah \calert{Warning!} blah blah blah}.

\sout{\clight{blah blah blah}}

\st{blah blah blah}.

%\st{\textcolor{gray}{blah blah}}
%\st{\clight{blah blah}} % gives `Argument of \clight has an extra }.`

\end{document}
```

There seem to be known issues regarding these packages: [Interaction between xcolor, ulem, and no-break spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324300/interaction-between-xcolor-ulem-and-no-break-spaces), [soul: broken highlighting with xcolor when using \selectcolormodel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48501/soul-broken-highlighting-with-xcolor-when-using-selectcolormodel), [acro acronym not recognized inside the soul package's strikeout command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367654/acro-acronym-not-recognized-inside-the-soul-packages-strikeout-command..). very disappointing that no better solutions have been developed.

P.S. using `\sout`, it looks like the horizontal line is behind the text, not over it... very strange

Comment: Your MWE compiles fine on my machine with `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)` or with `LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)`. Have you an up-to-date installation?

Comment: @NBur even with the commented out portion inserted?

Comment: Sorry, commented too fast… That was really a m**W**e!

Answer (score 2):

soul is fragile and doesn't like commands in the arguments. See the documentation for some background info. In your case it works if you add additional braces *and* color word by word:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\clight}[1]{\textcolor{white!70!black}{#1}}
\definecolor{alert}{RGB}{255, 10, 61} % 1/20/22
\newcommand{\calert}[1]{\textcolor{alert}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\st{blah blah blah}.

\st{{\textcolor{gray}{blah}} {\textcolor{gray}{blah}}}

\st{{\clight{blah}} {\clight{blah}}} 

\end{document}
```

A much more robust solution is to use lualatex and the `lua-ul` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\clight}[1]{\textcolor{white!70!black}{#1}}
\definecolor{alert}{RGB}{255, 10, 61} % 1/20/22
\newcommand{\calert}[1]{\textcolor{alert}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\st{blah blah blah}.

\st{\textcolor{gray}{blah blah}}
\st{\clight{blah blah}} %

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: are there truly no "native" LaTeX packages that have more robust underlining/strikethrough capabilities? If so, do you have any idea why? Is it particularly difficult, or just something the community has overlooked?

Comment: it is very difficult if you want also hyphenation and line breaking. The alternative method to the token analysis done by soul would be dedicated fonts with strikethrough characters. The luatex version works with attributes which makes everything much easier.

Comment: @D.R there is also `ulem`, that one is more robust than `soul` but lacks automatic hyphenation (manual hyphenation with `\-` works though).

Comment: @Skillmon I can't get `ulem` to work with a whole paragraph of text, like I mentioned in my question above.

Comment: @D.R if your lines are equally spaced you can also use Ti*k*Z (there are solutions for this on the site).